# Veal stock substitute

Tags: stock, veal

In the UK I was fortunate enough to live near a butcher who sold refrigerated real veal stock - goopy and gelatinous. Now I live in Zurich where this proves impossible to buy. You can, however, buy *kalbsfond* which comes in a jar and apparently is made of veal, and doesn't taste horribly wrong, but appears to have no gelatine in; it is however browner and has a sort of powdery residue. What's a good substitute? My current substitute, boringly enough is *kalbsfond* and gelatine sheet. My interest is in using the stock to thicken and flavour sauces of a traditional French style.

Comment: probably not an answer:  make your own veal stock.  via web search, it looks like there are butchers who sell veal in Zurich

Comment: @jim it's easy to buy veal in Zurich (for instance for making Wiener schnitzel), but less easy to buy veal bones. Still, while this is a decent suggestion, it's a lot of work compared to buying (or faking) a stock.

Comment: I completely agree that making a stock is tougher.  my job isn't in the food business.  I only make stock a dozen times a year.  most of the stock I use is from a "soup base" concentrate that comes in small tubs.